# How to handle 404 Not Found in Ember REST Adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

I am using Ember 1.0.0 pre and use the REST Adapter to fetch an object from a Rails API.
I render a template if the object is found via the REST API and set the found model object as the model of the view. In order to do that, I use the model hook in the Route and everything seems to work fine.
Naturally, I want to render some special 404 template/view if the model object is not found.
The problem is that the model hook stops the processing if the REST adapter returns an error.

I saw in the ember-data roadmap that error handling is not yet supported.

**What I don't understand is why does Ember not call the redirect hook in the Route if an error occurs.** (And how can I handle such errors?)

Here is the Route:

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
  this.render('mymodel')    
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return App.MyModel.find(params.id);
  },
  redirect: function() {
    // I want to redirect to another route
    // if the model is not found via the find method.
    // However, this hook is not called if the previous one
    // does not return an object
  }
})
```

Is there any other solution? I know, I can check in the template if the model of the view is null and then render a partial template, but the problem is that the view is not rendered at all (I assume exactly because of the same problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create an abstract, and then have your routes extend that route. I've [created a working JSFiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/xaA3d/), but please let me explain.

Our `App.IndexRoute` can contain all of the logic in `App.MyRedirectRoute`, but because other routers might require the same functionality, it's better to create an abstract so if/when you need this functionality again, you can just extend `App.MyRedirectRoute` again to prevent re-writing code.

Unfortunately Ember.JS doesn't have the logic to detect if the model is empty and to render a different page. Maybe in the future this will be a reality! *(It would be lovely!)*, but we can do this ourselves.

Our `App.IndexRoute` is nice and simple:

```
App.IndexRoute = App.MyRedirectRoute.extend({
    defaultRender: 'home',
    errorRedirectTo: '404',

    model: function(params) {
        // We've found a model!
        return Ember.Object.create({ params: params });
        // We've not found a model!
        return null;
    }
});
```

If the model is valid then we can render the `home` route, otherwise we'll render the `404` route. Nothing changes in returning the model from the route.

It's the `renderTemplate` that contains our logic for rendering the appropriate view. So we therefore overload the `renderTemplate` method in our abstract and do the logic stuff:

- If the model is considered empty by Ember.JS, then we'll render the view as specified by `errorRedirectTo`;
- If the model is considered valid, then we'll render the default, as specified by `defaultRender`.

If the model is empty, then we'll simply specify that we wish to render the 404 route (`errorRedirectTo`), but by default we'll want to render the default route (`defaultRender`).

To see it in action, take a look at the aforementioned JSFiddle. Comment out line #27 to see the 404 page rendered, because the object is `null`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your time and the long response. Indeed, that works as expected. However, it doesn't work out of the box if I use the `App.MyModel.find(params.id);` I ended up checking whether or not the returned object has the "_data" attribute. If yes, I return the model and if not I return null. Would you consider this check safe?

Comment: I would say so, but if you have any unusual problems relating to it, then keep this in mind as a possible cause.

Comment: There were some further issues, but I believe these were caused because of ember-data. As I decided not to use it, until it is stable, your solution seems to do the job quite good. So thanks again, I am accepting your answer.